# How to mark a status close/open in Path for Custom Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, record

I created a custom object and a Path based on the status field. However, there are a few status which would be equal to closed. How do I mark it as the end of the process like Closed Won and Closed Lost on Opportunity?

Comment: any more details if you can provide??? if you can explain it little more?

Comment: I set up a Path in a custom object and used a picklist with the following values: open, completed, rejected. Now, i want it to work like opportunity Stage where completed and rejected is both equal to close. In opportunity path, there's closed won and closed lost right, so i want the status completed and rejected to work the same. like they are both a possible end result of the path without using record types.

Comment: I think the question makes perfect sense, but I don't know whether or not there's a way to do that. On Opportunity, it's controlled by a special field defined on the Stage picklist entry, which isn't applicable to other objects.